# Search XML file and return results using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, xml, search

I'm trying to search a locally based XML using 'key words', with the goal of returning the results to the screen using jQuery.

For example, if I was to search for a keyword of 'iPhone 7' in the XML, the results displayed on the screen would be a description of the iPhone 7.

I have made it as far that I have created a search bar using Bootstrap.

Have puzzled over this for quite a while, so any help would be appreciated on this.

The jQuery

HTML

```
<form action="" class="search-form">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="search" class="sr-only">Search</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search for current topics, e.g., iPhone"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
        <div id="search_output"></div>
      </div>
```

jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search').on('keyup', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "iphones.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: parseXML
        });
    });
});
function parseXML(xml){
    var searchFor = $('#search').val();
    var reg = new RegExp(searchFor, "i");
    $(xml).find('entry').each(function(){
        var title = $(this).find('title').text();
        var titleSearch = title.search(reg);
        var desc = $(this).find('description').text();
        var descSearch = desc.search(reg);
        $('#search_output').empty();
        if(titleSearch > -1){
            $('#search_output').append('Found <i>'+searchFor+'<\/i> in title: '+title.replace(reg, '<b>'+searchFor+'</b>')+'<br \/>');
        }
        if(descSearch > -1){
            $('#search_output').append('Found <i>'+searchFor+'<\/i> in description: '+desc.replace(reg, '<b>'+searchFor+'</b>')+'<br \/>');
        }
    });    
}
```

XML

```
    <rss version="2.0">
<channel>
    <title> iPhone Reviews </title>
    <description> Review of iPhones </description>
    <language>en-gb</language>
            <item>
                <title> iPhone 7 </title>
                <description> iPhone 7 released in 2016 </description>
            </item>
            <item>
                <title> iPhone 8 </title>        
                <description> iPhone 8 released in 2017 </description>
            </item>
            <item>
                <title> iPhone X</title>      
                <description> iPhone X released in 2017</description>
            </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I have identified the  element of #search_output as where I want the search results to display, but at this stage nothing is appearing, and the screen just refreshes.

Comment: Makes no sense to get same file every key stroke when you could load that data once and store in variable. Also don't see any `<entry>` tags...try `$(xml).find('item')` to look for `<item>`

Comment: Where do the <entry> tags need to go?

Comment: What entry tags?...I don't see any in the xml but you are looking for them in the jQuery

Comment: You have said above that I need to include entry tags, I don't know where these go.

Comment: No...I said that's what your code is looking for ... but there are none. You need to look for `<item>`

Comment: This somewhat fixes the issue, thank you. However, it does not display the information when I hit enter.  It finds the information as I type.

Comment: Hitting enter will submit form if there is a submit button

Comment: Nope, as specified, this does not happen.

Comment: Well nothing else shown would cause page to refresh